# To identify which button is pressed and to get the corresponding data associated with it

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, web

When the user clicks on the button, I want to get the mobile no. of the pressed user.
The data is stored in an Array List and displayed in a table using for loop.

Technologies used in backend:
-JSP
-Servlet
-JAVA

```
<%

        ArrayList<HospitalDTO> list=(ArrayList<HospitalDTO>)request.getAttribute("arrayList");
        for(HospitalDTO hsp:list)
        {
            long no=hsp.getNumber();
            //session.setAttribute("contactNumber",no);
            String name=hsp.getName();
            Date nextDD=hsp.getNextDD();
            Date lastDD=hsp.getLastDD();
            out.println("<tr><td class='text-center'>"+no+"</td><td class='text-center'>"+name+"</td><td class='text-center'>"+lastDD+

                    "</td><td class='text-center'>"+nextDD+"</td><td class='text-center'><form action='SendSmsServlet' method='post'><input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' value='Notify Donor'></form></td></tr>");
        }

    %>
```

Thanks for any support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the phone number as a form field in order to be sent back to the server.

Here is an example of the form code. Adjust to your needs and then replace the part of your code between `<form>` and `</form>`.

```
"<form action='SendSmsServlet' method='post'>"+
    "<input type='hidden' name='PhoneNumber' value='"+no+"' />"+
    "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' value='Notify Donor'>"+
"</form>"
```